# Explain the output obtained by using the following Macro

Tags: c, data-structures, macros, c-preprocessor

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ABC(x) DEF(x)
#define DEF(x) GHI(x)
#define GHI(x) printf(x)

int main(void)
{
  int x = 100;
  int y = 200;
  ABC(("Sum of x + y is %d", x + y));

  return 0;
}
```

The output of the above code gives **Invalid memory reference (SIGSEGV)**.

Comment: Run it through a preprocessor and look at the code that will really be compiled. And learn about the [*comma operator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Comma_operator).

Comment: Also, your compiler should give you plenty of warnings for this code - don't ignore warnings !

Comment: Your code boils down to this: `printf(("Sum of x + y is %d", x + y));`. Any more questions? What output did _you_ expect?

Answer (score 1):

If you had considered the warnings you could have identified yourself

```
macro1.c: In function ‘main’:
macro1.c:11:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘printf’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
   ABC(("Sum of x + y is %d", x + y));
   ^
In file included from macro1.c:1:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:362:12: note: expected ‘const char * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 extern int printf (const char *__restrict __format, ...);
            ^
macro1.c:11:3: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
   ABC(("Sum of x + y is %d", x + y));
```

It is clearly indicating you are passing `int` instead of `string` to `printf`.
Because your code will look like below after preprocesing.

```
printf(("Sum of x + y is %d", x + y))
```

To make it work you can do as below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ABC(x,y) DEF(x,y)
#define DEF(x,y) GHI(x,y)
#define GHI(x,y) printf(x,y)

int main(void)
{
  int x = 100;
  int y = 200;
  ABC("Sum of x + y is %d", x + y);

  return 0;
}
```

or you can remove parenthesis around `x` in `printf`

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ABC(x) DEF(x)
#define DEF(x) GHI(x)
#define GHI(x) printf x

int main(void)
{
  int x = 100;
  int y = 200;
  ABC(("Sum of x + y is %d", x + y));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: it can also be fixed with a smaller change in the original code : `#define GHI(x) printf x`